# How do I get separate bundles for Aurelia vendor files and Aurelia app files using Webpack?

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I have this basic setup for webpack:

```js
{
    context: rootDir,
    entry: {
        main: scriptsPath + "Main.ts",
        app: [/* this is filled by the aurelia-webpack-plugin */]
    },
    output: {
        path: destDir,
        library: "[name]",
        filename: "[name]-bundle.js"
    },
    module: {...loaders},
    resolve: {...},
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "main",
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),            
        new AureliaWebpackPlugin({
            src: appPath,
            root: rootDir
        }),
    ]
};
```

My `Main.ts` only imports all the `aurelia-*` packages that come with the skeleton app, along with Jquery and Bootstrap. And as expected, I get two separate bundles named `main-bundle.js` and `app-bundle.js`. But when run, the browser throws the following error:

`Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/compose'.`

I have traced it down to the aurelia webpack plugin not generating the proper context map that is used by the `webpackContextResolve` function. I am at a loss on how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Environment details:

- Windows 7 x64
- Node v6.0.0
- NPM v3.10.7
- Webpack v1.13.2
- Aurelia v1.1.0

**UPDATE**

I followed instructions on [this issue](https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/issues/66) and updated **Webpack to 2.1.0-beta.24** and am still encountering this error and many others similar to it:

```
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/binding-mode-behaviors'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/repeat'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/with'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/if'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/compose'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-router/route-href'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/update-trigger-binding-behavior'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-router/router-view'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/signal-binding-behavior'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/debounce-binding-behavior'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/sanitize-html'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/replaceable'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/hide'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/show'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/throttle-binding-behavior'. app-bundle.js:42:9
Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-templating-resources/focus'.
```